# Что делать с ошибкой write tcp 127.0.0.1:3000->127.0.0.1:XXXXX: write: broken pipe при выполнении http запроса

Tags: golang

При выполнении http запроса получаю ошибку write tcp 127.0.0.1:3000->127.0.0.1:XXXXX: write: broken pipe. Ошибка возникает, если клиент разорвал соединение. Что делать в такой ситуации мне не ясно. Может кто-нибудь сможет подсказать, что делать.

Так же если при выполнении хендлера я в горутинах делаю http запросы на другие ресурсы и получаю ошибку context canceled. Тоже не понятно что с этим делать

Comment: В смысле «что делать?»?  Что ваша задача говорит, то и делать.  Можно логгировать, можно куда-то отсылать.  Добавьте, пожалуйста, деталей в вопрос.

Comment: @Ainar-G Задачи нет, есть много логов с этой ошибкой, я понимаю, что клиент закрыл соединение с сервером. Но сервер по какой-то причине не получил сообщение, если не ошибаюсь это сообщение RST, и продолжает писать в закрытый канал. Вот здесь у меня и возникает непонимание, в какую сторону смотреть. По какой-то причине ошибок стало очень много. Причину тоже пока не удалось установить.

Comment: Сетевые ошибки могут возникать без каких-либо предупреждений.  Если вы хотите не выводить их в логи, вам нужно отловить эту ошибку с помощью, например, [`errors.Is`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#Is), и решать, что делать или не делать.